# How to sharp blurry text on product labels

Tags: product-photography

I am struggling with blurry text on product labels. My image is just on focus but I am not getting the labels to sharpen. What camera settings or lens do I need for?

Comment: Can you please upload 1-2 sample images that show the issue? That really makes it easier for people to give you a suitable answer. Additionally, could you describe what process you use to take the photos? I.e.: what settings did you use, do you use a tri-pod, what lighting do you use?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say without seeing your images.

First, see if the labels are actually well printed. Sometimes they have a print error where two colors making the text are not aligned.

From there see if:

- You have enough resolution
- It is not noise due to high ISO
- The aperture is not too wide, try using F8 - F11.
- You do not have motion blur, due to slow shutter speed, camera shake, lens stabilization.
- If your lens is simply not capable of making sharp images.

And last you can apply some sharpening in post.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the aperture narrow in your camera setting when you are taking a photo of the product, you will be able to keep the entire object in focus.  Along with this you can also use wide angle lens.